# Failing to send web request to a CAS server on Tomcat

Tags: powershell, http, tomcat, cas

I am trying to reproduce some HTTP requests I launched with the Postman Chrome extension on a PowerShell script.

The goal of my request is to recieve a ticket by logging in to a CAS server.

I wrote the following PowerShell (I used [variable] notation for anonymisation purposes) :

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true} ;
$postParams = @{username='[username]';password='[password]'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://[host]:[port]/cas/v1/tickets/ -Method POST -
Body $postParams'
```

But the Tomcat server answers with a **HTTP 404** error whereas the same request on Postman provides me with the ticket and works perfectly.

Comment: The request does not appear in fiddler ;Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\request.ps1:8 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://[host]:[port]/cas/v1/tickets/ -Method POST -Body ...
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: Actually you solved my issue, the URL was wrong because of a too fast copy/paste

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I deleted my comment and added an answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

404 indicates that something is wrong with the URL you are sending the request. You could use fiddler to trace the request and check the URL